# How to specifically display the parent field's name instead of just the ids. Error encountered null pointer exception

Tags: trigger

I am getting in the line 39 `propertyName` and `customerName` as NullPointerException if I use the child to parent `Property__r.Name` and `Customer__r.Name` but there is a value in that record. This codes are under the isAfter and isUpdate trigger.
if I use `pb.Property__c` and `pb.Customer__c` , I just get the id's not the name. Please see screenshot below

[image]

[image: in]

---

```apex
String propertyName = pb.Property__r.Name;
String customerName = pb.Customer__r.Name;
//Html body setup and replace
String htmlBody = template.HtmlValue;
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Property_Booking__c.CreatedBy}', recordOwnerName);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Property_Booking__c.CreatedDate}', string.valueOfGmt(pb.CreatedDate));
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Property_Booking__c.Property__c}', propertyName);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Property_Booking__c.Customer__c}', customerName);
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Property_Booking__c.Status__c}', pb.Status__c);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I see related data in my Apex, or why are related records showing up as \`null\`?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318730/why-cant-i-see-related-data-in-my-apex-or-why-are-related-records-showing-up-a)

Comment: Please do not post code or error text exclusively as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. (Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor.) Instead, copy your code and paste it in the SFSE editor with three backticks (```) above and below it in order to format it as a code block. Similarly, format error text with a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block.

Comment: hello i did not post a code as scereenshot, i specifically posted it my code as a code block and as for the error screenshot how else would I show my errors if not using screenshots? Kindly double check my codes are in a code block I just highlighted them all and pressed command + K

Comment: trigger context never includes parent fields; you have to query for them (bulkified)

Comment: I realize that you did you not post code as a screenshot, but my comment is one that I have saved, that I just copy/paste when needed, and which includes info about both code & errors. *"[H]ow else would I show my errors if not using screenshots?"* By highlighting the text found in your original error pop-up box, right-clicking and selecting "Copy" (or, on a Mac you can possibly press `Cmd+C`, or `Ctrl+C` on a Windows machine) to copy the error text, then paste (right-click > "Paste"; `Cmd+V`; `Ctrl+V`) that text in your question and - as I previously stated - format it with a (>).

Comment: And also please note that I said "exclusively" - which means that is fine to post errors (and some code) as screenshots, but if you do, please *also* copy/paste the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, i just created a formula field that will display the name of the master then I used that in my trigger.

answer from here
[How to populate owner name instead of id from a child object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215904/how-to-populate-owner-name-instead-of-id-from-a-child-object)

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable (actually encouraged) on SFSE that if you found the solution and added it as an answer to your own question, to accept your own answer as the correct or best answer. It helps tidy up the site as well as making it more obvious to future readers.